# How large should the mysql temp folder be when altering table information like auto increment?

Tags: mysql, tmp

If I have 500GB table size, how big should the temp folder be in order to alter table information? I will be configuring temp in my.cnf and, in this example, I have 64 GB physical ram.

Comment: What version of MySQL?  Please provide the `ALTER` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of the temp folder seems irrelevant according to the "Performance and Space Requirements" section in the manual for `ALTER` as the space is taken from the same location where the original table is located: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html

> The temporary copy of the table is created in the database directory of the original table

and

> For InnoDB tables, an ALTER TABLE operation that uses the COPY algorithm on a table that resides in a **shared tablespace can increase** the amount of space used by the tablespace. Such operations require as much additional space as the data in the table plus indexes.

...

> `ALTER TABLE with DISCARD ... PARTITION ... TABLESPACE or IMPORT ... PARTITION ... TABLESPACE` **does not create any temporary tables** or temporary partition files.

...

Comment: HBruijn if the database is version is 5.5 which I think has no instant algorithm (or it has) it will use the copy algorithm and size will increase because of copy?